# Always getting "no data" response in AWS Gateway with success code 200

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, async-await, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to get response from lambda in AWS API Gateway. I always get no data message with 200. But I return different message in lambda. Gateway and Lambda connected with non-proxy, because I have to add X-AMZ-Invocation-Type : event for async response. How can I change body of response using lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message you see is not coming from lambda. At async invocation; api gateway returns the response first, then make a request to lambda "asynchronously". it is normal you to see different messages between lambda and api gateway test. You can't change response the body of response using lambda.

No response will be return with async integration (couldn't find it documentation to support this - but tried several times)

Comment: you're welcome, hope aws improves this feature with predefined response for async invocations.

Comment: In async invocation, Lambda is first invoked and then a 200 status is sent to the client. You could add a custom message using mapping template in integration response.